# SQL code to create a table

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the SQL code to create a table ? I am running into error I don't know what I am doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: Error
SQL query: Documentation


SELECT DISTINCT candidate.Cand_ID,candidate.Cand_Name
 FROM candidate,interview 
    WHERE interview.Interview_Result = 'Pass'
     AND interview.Interview_Round IN ('First','Second')
        AND interview.Cand_ID = candidate.Cand_ID
   ORDER BY candidate.Cand_ID DESC LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation

#1146 - Table 'kameikajaved-problem1.candidate' doesn't exist

Comment: Why are you using Select if the table doesn't exist and you need to create it.

Comment: Please consider actually using a title for that picture and maybe include the query itself in your question. You could add 4 spaces/a tab in front of each line in order to mark it as code. Are you sure your query is correct? It's kind of strange that `candidate` would not exist. As for your question refer to the manual: [MySQL 5.7 14.1.18 CREATE TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT candidate.Cand_ID,candidate.Cand_Name 
FROM candidate,interview 
WHERE interview.Interview_Result = 'Pass' 
    AND interview.Interview_Round IN ('First','Second') 
    AND interview.Cand_ID = candidate.Cand_ID 
ORDER BY candidate.Cand_ID DESC LIMIT
```

Use `INNER JOIN` here. It seems you are joining two tables and putting where clause based on another table. Try this instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT candidate.Cand_ID,candidate.Cand_Name 
FROM candidate INNER JOIN interview ON candidate.yourcommonfield = interview.yourcommonfield 
WHERE interview.Interview_Result = 'Pass' 
    AND interview.Interview_Round IN ('First','Second') 
ORDER BY candidate.Cand_ID DESC LIMIT
```

> What is the SQL code to create a table?

You should use `CREATE TABLE` query in order to create your desired table.

Comment: The common field would be `Cand_ID` he actually is doing an inner join already, just in an old fashioned way. See also [Using JOIN keyword or not](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/78225/using-join-keyword-or-not).

Comment: sorry about that. I didn't see the joined field there because of query construction from his question.

Comment: Consider removing the `AND interview.Cand_ID = candidate.Cand_ID` from your solution as it would be redundant. :)

Comment: I am directly executing the code. I thought once I execute the code , then it will create the table. Is not that right ? Or how do you create a table in the SQL?

Comment: CREATE TABLE tablename (column1 data_type(size),column2 data_type(size),column3 data_type(size),...and so on) This should give you a headstart.